# How to define Typescript properties and types for a React Action Hook Store

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context, react-state-management

I am creating a react state management store using hooks, after the 'Action Hooks pattern' described [here](https://tannerlinsley.com/blog/react-hooks-the-rebirth-of-state-management) by Tanner Linsley.

I am learning Typescript and am trying to create this project using it but keep running into an error when calling the custom hook to consume the store:

> 'Property 'useStore' does not exist on type '() => { Provider: ({ initialValue, children }: { initialValue?: {}; children: any; }) => Element; useStore: () => any;}' ts(2339)

I tested it in plain react and it is working, so it is a type or property definition issue with Typescript.

Generic Store created (No typescript errors):

```
interface IState {}

const initialState: IState = {}

export default function newStore() {
  const context = React.createContext<IState>(initialState)

  const Provider = ({ initialValue = {}, children }): JSX.Element => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialValue)
    const contextValue = useMemo(() => [state, setState], [state])

    return <context.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</context.Provider>
  }
  const useStore = () => useContext(context)

  return { Provider, useStore }
}
```

Store Action Hooks (the error is shown for both instances of useStore):

```
import store from "./makeStore";

export const useGalleryOpen = () => {
  const [{ galleryOpen }] = store.useStore()
  return galleryOpen
}

export const useGalleryToggle = () => {
  const [_, setState] = store.useStore()
  return () =>
    setState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      galleryOpen: !prev.galleryOpen,
    }))
}
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point of the problem (it's visible in your code sandbox and I've edited your question to include it) is the `store` definition.

You define store as `import store from "./makeStore";`

So `store` is a function that, when called, returns an object containing

```js
{
  Provider: any;
  useStore(): any;
}
```

when you consume it with `store.useStore()` you're making the mistake. `store` is a function which return value is an object containing the `useStore` function.

Everything goes well replacing

```js
store.useStore()
```

with

```js
store().useStore()
```

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: I have tried explicitly defining Provider and useStore with an interface I put any for now to test eg. 
`interface IStore {
  Provider: any
  useStore(): any
}
newStore(): IStore {...`
But then useStore returns an error 
`Property 'useStore' does not exist on type '() => IStore'`
Am I not defining the useStore function properly?

Comment: You use `store.useStore()` in your code but where is `store` declared? I'd like to see its type 

Comment: I import store from ./makeStore. The code fragments are seperate components. Therefore in the above case `function store(): IStore` and I think I am declaring useStore in IStore..hmm?
[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/n32qppnlp4?fontsize=12&module=%2Fstore%2Fui.tsx&view=editor)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the solution  as I thought, the problem was the `store` declaration/consume